# Getting comment ID from URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web

I'm writing a simple forum with ASP, using the MVC template with user login.
It's really new to me and kind of difficult to grasp. I managed to implement posting topics and comments, deleting them but the edit is giving me some major problem.
Here's my action:

```
public ActionResult EditReply()
        {

            int.TryParse((string)Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"], out int id);
            Topic topic = db.Topics.Find(id);
            int.TryParse((string)Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"], out int commentId);
            Comment comment = topic.Comments.Find(x => x.Id == commentId);

            return View(comment);       
        }
```

I get "object reference not set to an instance of an object". Debugging shows me that the comment variable is empty due to unsuccessful getting of the ID because it seems that the commentId variable's value is 0. It works for topicId but won't work for the commentId. However, the URL where I get the error shows http://localhost:49834/Home/EditReply?TopicId=16&CommentId=43
so the Id is there but I cannot extract it. I'm really new to ASP. Any sort of input will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't it appear as parameters on EditReply method? 
```public ActionResult EditReply(int TopicId, int CommentId)```

Comment: Just change you method to `public ActionResult EditReply(int topicId, int commentId)` and the parameters will be correctly bound (not sure how you thought `topicId` would be bound to a route value named `id`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using ASP.NET MVC then a simple update to your Action's signature will get the values you need.

```
public ActionResult EditReply(int TopicId, int CommentId)
{
    Topic topic = db.Topics.Find(TopicId);
    Comment comment = topic.Comments.Find(x => x.Id == CommentId);

    return View(comment);       
}
```

This will use the default model binding that is built in to MVC.

Comment: Thank you very much for the input. I haven't really read into MVC, I just took it head on. I have to read on model binding. I changed it as you've written, changed the model in my EditView.cshtml and it works like a charm. Can you recommend any good materials to soak up on MVC knowledge that is practical and has enough examples ?Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should probably check out the Getting Started tutorial on Microsoft Docs -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/ .It will guide you the various aspects of writing an MVC application. Have fun

Comment: Thanks. Another quick question - since my other functionalities are unlike edit, what is supposed to go in the Post EditReply ?
I tried the same logic for accessing the IDs and then saving in DB but it doesn't work, again I seem to be getting null values for my IDs.
Any help is appreciated, cheers

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking, although I'm sure that if you ask another question, with more detail than you can put in a comment, I'm sure you'll get the information you need.

Comment: I get the comment from the EditReply action and I need the Save button to override the previous values for the same topic/commentId. So I have another EditReply action which is a [HttpPost]. I am not sure what logic goes inside the Post EditReply action. Cheers

Comment: Additional questions should be asked in a new question. Comments are not the best place to do this.

Answer (score 1):

MVC will do the work for you. Define your action as

```
public ActionResult EditReplay(int topicId, int commentId) { …
```

And the model binding will use the query string or form values to populate parameters. With MVC you rarely, if ever, need to directly look at the request.

(If the parameters are optional, make the types nullable: `int? commentId`.)